# How is a pointer composed in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I would like to create the equivalent of %p tag in the printf and write the hexadecimal value of a pointer. But I wanted to know what does the `0x` and the 4 first characters mean ? Because when I translate it from decimal to hexadecimal, I only have the 8 last characters.
So what are the three parts that compose a pointer please ?

I mean : When I try to convert a pointer in hexadecimal (with my own function), I get 8 characters.

When I use the %p flag of the printf, I get a return that looks like this : [0x][7ffd][the 8 last characters I get] (without the [])

Here is my conversion code (It has only to work for hexa, binary, and octal) :

```
char    *convert_to_base(int nb, char *base_str)
{
  char  *result;
  int   i;
  int   has_begin;
  int   base;
  int   diviser;

  base = my_strlen(base_str);
  result = malloc(sizeof(char) * 12);
  diviser = (base >= 10) ? my_power_rec(base, 7) : my_power_rec(base, 10);
  has_begin = 0;
  i = 0;
  while (diviser != 0)
    {
      if (!has_begin)
        has_begin = (base_str[nb / diviser] != '0') ? 1 : 0;
      if (has_begin)
        {
          result[i] = base_str[nb / diviser];
          nb =  nb % diviser;
          i += 1;
        }
      diviser /= base;
    }
  result[i] = '\0';
  return (result);
}
```

I use openSUSE

Comment: I'm not very clear..can you re-word?

Comment: `0x` is a prefix.. but first 4 characters? They are actually digits...

Comment: Yes but digits in hexadecimal, which uses characters

Comment: Sooo...? The rest are digits in hexadecimal too. I hope you see them.

Comment: You should post the conversion code. Maybe you are looping for a wrong sizeof...

Comment: %p is implementation defined in its format. You would need to look at the documentation for your implementation compiler/library in order to find out the meaning of the format %p uses.

Comment: What your platform converts pointers for use with `printf("%p", ...)` may be irrelevant to why your conversion code shows a different result. Please post your code and name your platform.

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Answer (score 2):

According to the standard's specification of the `p` specifier,

> The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is
>                       converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined
>                       manner.

That said, in some platforms (e.g. Linux) pointers may be treated as `unsigned long`s for the purposes of `printf`. Therefore what you see is the value of the pointer as an integer, converted in base 16.

Without knowing your platform, that's as much as can be said about it.

Comment: Ok, so I think my problem comes because I'm using unsigned int instead of long, thanks. And I'm using Linux openSUSE

Answer (score 0):

The `0x` is just a prefix, that indicates that is a hexadecimal number. The numbers are just the value (all of them), the amount of numbers is because of the size of the address, and that depends on the OS Architecture.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the format of the pointer, use the information from [`<inttypes.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/inttypes.h.html#tag_13_20) — defined by C99 and C11:

```
uintptr_t ptrval = (uintptr_t)void_pointer;  // Or any other object pointer

printf("0x%.8" PRIXPTR "\n", ptrval);
```

This might produce:

```
0x7FFF8192AFE0
```

for example.  It's a notation I use frequently.  Clearly, you can use `snprintf()` instead of `printf()`, etc.